# Using proof of equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

I just wanted to make sure whether I was on the right track or not with this.

Let $r\in\mathbb{R}_{\ne0}$. Use a proof of equivalence to show the following:

> $$r\in\mathbb{Q} \iff \frac{5r-1}{2r}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

$p$: "$r$ is rational"

$q$: "$\frac{5r-1}{2r}$ is rational"

So to prove equivalence, we have to show $p \rightarrow q$ and $q \rightarrow p$.

In order to prove $q \rightarrow p$, suppose $\frac{5r-1}{2r}$ is rational, so $\frac{5r-1}{2r} = \frac ab$ for some non-zero integer $a,\ b$.

So, isolating for r would get: $r = \frac b{5b-2a}$. So here's my question:

Am I correct in saying that this would mean $q \rightarrow p$ is false because $(5b-2a)$ is not a non-zero integer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is it really possible that $5b-2a = 0$ ? That would mean that $a=\frac{5}{2}b$.

Remember you defined $a$ and $b$ with the relation $\frac{5r-1}{2r} = \frac{a}{b}$. What would $a=\frac{5}{2}b$ imply ?

Comment: What I was thinking is that, for example, when a = 5 and b = 2, wouldn't 5b-2a = 0? And that would make the denominator 0.

Comment: I had understood that. What I tried to tell you is that when you say "$\frac{5r-1}{2r}$ is rational so there exists $a$ and $b$ such as $\frac{5r-1}{2r} = \frac{a}{b}$", you implicitely add some constraints on the value of a and b, which forbid $5b-2a = 0$. Because if $\frac{5r-1}{2r} = \frac{a}{b}$, then $2ra = 5rb-b$, so $r(5b-2a)=b$. As $b \neq 0$ since $\frac{a}{b}$ exists, $5b-2a$ can't be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

how is (5b - 2a) a NOT non zero integer?

let b = an integer,
    a = integer.

you have a non zero integer.